# How to store formula with calculated value using xlsx-populate

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx, xlsx-populate

I want to set formula of a cell then store the calculated value in the same cell as we do in Excel but when I call `cell.formula('A1*10')` will set formula on cell, but the result is not calculated until I open and save the sheet using Excel.

I need to create and load XLSX file without to open it in external application.

If I do `cell.formula('A1*10').value(10)` removes the formula property and I see only value `10` in the cell.

Is there way to set formula and result together on cell?